# Dynamically add text on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I am creating a basic raster graphics editor app (just started) and I am having trouble adding text dynamically to the canvas.

The app has 2 divisions. Left side is tool box, Right side is the editor canvas.

The user will select a tool from the left side (Add text button), and then click anywhere on the canvas to add text (why children canvas inside parent canvas? well I want the main canvas to have multiple canvas for text shapes images etc, since a single canvas can't hold multiple context).

HTML:

```
<div class="app">
    <aside class="app__tools">
        <button class="btn tools__btn tools__text">Add Text</button>
    </aside>

    <canvas class="app__drawing-board">

    </canvas>
</div>
```

Selecting Toolbox JavaScript (Works fine):

```
// TOOLBOX
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.tools__btn');

let button_selected = false;

for (let i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', e => {
        console.log('BUTTON: clicked');
        console.log('button selected', button_selected);

        const attributes = e.target.getAttribute('class').split(' ');
        const selected = attributes.filter(className => className === 'selected').length === 0;

        console.log('selected', selected);
        button_selected = selected;

        if (selected) attributes.push('selected');
        else attributes.splice(-1, 1);

        e.target.setAttribute('class', attributes.join(' '));
    });
}
```

Hovering over canvas when tool button is selected (Works fine):

```
// CANVAS 
const canvas = document.getElementsByClassName('app__drawing-board')[0];

canvas.addEventListener('mouseover', e => {
    console.log('CANVAS: mouseover');
    console.log('button selected', button_selected);

    e.target.style.cursor = button_selected? 'text' : 'auto';
});
```

Adding text to the canvas (Failing Here):

```
canvas.addEventListener('click', e => {
    if (button_selected) {
        console.log('CANVAS: clicked');
        console.log(e);

        const text_canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        const context = text_canvas.getContext('2d');

        text_canvas.class = 'drawing-board__text';

        context.font = '40pt Calibri';
        context.fillText('Hello World', e.pageX, e.pageY);

        canvas.appendChild(text_canvas);
        console.log(context);
    }
});
```

After clicking the canvas, my result is as:

```
<canvas class="app__drawing-board">
    <canvas>
    "

            "
    </canvas>
</canvas>
```

Even though, context prints:

```
CanvasRenderingContext2D {canvas: canvas, globalAlpha: 1, globalCompositeOperation: "source-over", filter: "none", imageSmoothingEnabled: true, …}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/danyal-imran/pen/WPQmvy

Comment: Why do you create a new <canvas> here? Simply call *getContext* on the one you already have in your document. Beside, <canvas> can not have visible children.

Comment: I read that you cannot have multiple context in a <canvas> (since I plan to add images, text, shapes, etc on the main drawing board), therefore I am thinking an alternate would be to have multiple <canvas> children in the main <canvas>? @Kaiido

Comment: Indeed you can have only one context per canvas element, but you can draw many times on it ;-), and you can request it several times too, it's just that getContext() will always return the same object. https://codepen.io/_-0-_/pen/PVPLJR

Comment: oh! by context I understood 1 graphic element, so if you drew once it works, but if drew another time, it would remove the previous one and draw another (boy was I wrong). thanks for clearning this and I see the pen is working fine, please add this as the answer below so I may close this thread, and thanks :) @Kaiido

Comment: I wonder how useful this question will be and did vote to close it, so I am lenient to answer it. To explain further why I did so, your misunderstanding is not isolated, and many will fall in the same in the future, however, the odds that they find **this** Q/A while facing this problem are very limited (for a start they would have to be trying to draw text, the ones trying to draw a rectangle or an image won't find it). So I'd rather see it closed or even deleted, even if I'm glad you could find the help you needed.